# how to add an existing folder with all its sub folders and contents to a solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to add an existing folder with all its sub folders and contents to a solution in visual studio 2012?
Some ways like zipping it or something like this...?

Comment: You can copy the folder and its subfolder in your solution folder. Then in VS 2012 you click the "Show ALl Files". You will then see the folder/folders as dimmed icons. Right click them and do "Include In Project"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a button in Solution Explorer called `Show All files`. Click on it and then select the folder you would like to include to the project:

[image]

Notice how the folders that are not part of the project are shown in white. You could pick the folder you want to include, right click on it and select `Include In Project` in the context menu. This will recursively include all files to the project.

Comment: 1 ^ is not enough for this.

Answer (score 0):

The folder you're showing is a 'Project Folder'.  This does not work for a folder that's created as a 'Solution Folder'. If you Right-click on the top node of the solution and you get the option to add a new 'Solution Folder.  However, when you do this VS, 2012 does not create a system folder with the corresponding name.

So far what I have found that works is to first create in Visual Studio a 'Solution Folder' with the relative path you want, and then in that 'Solution Folder' create a new project, being careful when creating the project to type in a system folder for the project with the relative path that matches. VS will then create the system folder for you, and install the project there. (Or you can drag-and-drop an existing file into the 'Solution Folder' you've created, if adding an existing file is what you're aiming for; the important point is to match the system relative path to the solution relative path.)

Comment: What I have found is to first create in Visual Studio a 'Solution Folder' with the relative path you want, and then in that 'Solution Folder' create a new project, being careful when creating the project to type in a system folder for the project with the relative path that matches. VS will then create the system folder for you, and install the project there. (Or you can drag-and-drop an existing file into the 'Solution Folder' you've created, if adding an existing file is what you're aiming for; the important point is to match the system relative path to the solution relative path.)